# Where does returned mail go

Tags: email

I'm sure it's probably dependent on the mail server, but in general when an email is rejected is it sent back to the email address in the "From" address or the "Reply To" address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returned mail goes to the address in the envelope (or the `Return-Path` header) ([section 6.1 of RFC 2821 (SMTP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-6.1)).

This *Envelope address* is an address that a mail user agent (MUA) would use when speaking SMTP to a mail server (the address in the `MAIL FROM:` command). When the SMTP server prepares to deliver the mail, it attaches that address to the message using the `Return-Path` header.

The `From` and `Reply-To` headers are unused here, these are the contents of a message. The envelope could note that the the communications department sent the mail (`MAIL FROM`), while the CTO was the drafter of the letter (`From`). Then any replies could be sent to the secretary (`Reply-To`). In any case, if the postman fails to deliver the letter, the mail would be returned to the communications department. Not *directly* to the CTO or secretary.

Comment: So the Explain it like I'm 5 answer is that it is returned to the sender (account owner), not the from, nor the reply to. Correct?

Comment: @invertedSpear Correct. Think of real world, the sender is noted on the envelope. The addressed names are written on the letter sealed by the envelope. (The sender is the `Return-Path` in a message which is set by the initial SMTP server from the `MAIL FROM` command).